# Average of last 3 months against a max date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image: My data looks like this:]

And the output that I am looking for is against every hhid, I want to calculate the average of the last 3 months of ttlasset and ttlimcome and the date(frdate) should be the max date.
So for every hhid, on max date,I want to calculate the average of last 3 months of ttlasset and ttlincome if the current month is not complete.
SO output should be like this:
[image]

This is the code that I used:

```
SELECT hhid, MAX(frdate), AVG(ttlincome),AVG(ttlasset)
FROM hhmonthlyprogress WHERE MONTH(frdate) = (SELECT MONTH(NOW())-1) OR MONTH(frdate) = (SELECT MONTH(NOW())-2) OR MONTH(frdate) = (SELECT MONTH(NOW())-3)
    FROM hhmonthlyprogress
```

Comment: what you mean by 'if current month is not complete'?

Comment: Means that only complete month.Like its 13th Oct today,so month is not complete.

Comment: yes, then why you included October calculations in your result set? I am trying to understand your logic.

Comment: I want to take the max date from frdate and average of last 3 months ie,september,august and ,july in the october.Aim is to bring all frdates to current month.As we move to november last 3 months would be October,September and August.Also plz check the query.Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will share my answer now. hhid- 5 results are not matching with your result set. Can you please re-check your result after examining my solution. Stay safe.

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE hhmonthlyprogress;` and `SELECT version();` then paste the result into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1 : finding max date for each hhid

```
SELECT hhid, MAX(DATE(frdate)) Maxdate
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress
GROUP BY hhid;
```

step 2 : using the query from step 1 as derived table and join with the `hhmonthlyprogress` table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress ha
  JOIN 
(SELECT hhid, MAX(DATE(frdate)) Maxdate
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress
GROUP BY hhid) hb
  ON ha.hhid=hb.hhid;
```

step 3: adding WHERE condition

```
SELECT * 
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress ha
  JOIN 
(SELECT hhid, MAX(DATE(frdate)) Maxdate
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress
GROUP BY hhid) hb
  ON ha.hhid=hb.hhid
  WHERE DATE(frdate) <= LAST_DAY(Maxdate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND DATE(frdate) >= LAST_DAY(Maxdate - INTERVAL 4 MONTH)+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Explanation for `WHERE` condition

```
LAST_DAY  (  Maxdate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH  )
 ^^          |  ^^^
returns last | returns previous month date based
day of the   | on Maxdate value.
month.       |
```

The second condition is basically the same but since there's no `FIRST_DAY()` function in MySQL that I know of, then I use `LAST_DAY()` from `Maxdate` value with 4 month previous interval then add `INTERVAL 1 DAY` to get the first day of next month after that.

step 4: Finalize query with `AVG()`:

```
SELECT ha.hhid,
       Maxdate,
       SUM(ttlasset)/3,
       SUM(ttlincome)/3
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress ha
  JOIN 
(SELECT hhid, MAX(DATE(frdate)) Maxdate
  FROM hhmonthlyprogress
GROUP BY hhid) hb
  ON ha.hhid=hb.hhid
  AND DATE(frdate) <= LAST_DAY(Maxdate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND DATE(frdate) >= LAST_DAY(Maxdate - INTERVAL 4 MONTH)+INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY ha.hhid;
```

Note: I've changed `AVG()` to `SUM()` then divide by 3 - as a representation of 3 months.

[Here is updated demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gkw4giZF)

Comment: Hi @FanoFN.Great way to explain the solution.The only issue is I want the date as max date for every hhid.Suppose for hhid=2,max(date) is 15/09/2022. And average of last 3 months for hhid should be last 3 months ie,September, August and July in the month of october. And if November,then last 3 months would be august, september and october.

Comment: For hhid = 5,max(frdate)=9/10/2022 and avg(ttlasset)=(September(7000)+August(0)+July(0))/3.Same with ttlincome.

Comment: I am taking `MAX(date)` for every `hhid`. Did you try the query in step 1 and see what does it return? See this example with much smaller dataset https://dbfiddle.uk/qRT0ws5E .. in there `MAX(date)` returns `2022-09-06`, right? So, according to your condition, the query should take August, July & June values for the average, correct? You can see the dates in `GROUP_CONCAT(frdate)` and the corresponding values for `ttlasset` with the said hhid+date combination.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for resolution and explanantion.Each row shows record for every month for each hhid.I want to see when was the last record was entered for that hhid and ttlasset and ttlincome for previous 3 months namely september, august and july,if we are in october.I ran the code you wrote.It is taking the max( date)for each hhid.

Comment: Ok, you said _"For hhid = 5,max(frdate)=9/10/2022 and avg(ttlasset)=(September(7000)+August(0)+July(0))/3.Same with ttlincome. "_ which will return the average `(7000+0+0)/3 = 2333.333333` .. but in your expected result it's `14566.67`. Can you explain why? Also, check my updated answer, I've updated the fiddle with your exact data sample.

Comment: Sry.It was by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check my SQL Code: I used CTE to solve it:

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT hhid, MAX(date) AS MaxDate, IF(MONTH(MAX(date)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()),MAX(date) - INTERVAL 4 MONTH,MAX(date) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS LowerLimit FROM YourTable GROUP BY hhid)SELECT cte.hhid, MaxDate, AVG(ttlasset) AS avg_asset, AVG(ttlincome) AS avg_income FROM cte JOIN YourTable ON cte.hhid = YourTable.hhid WHERE date <= MaxDate AND date >= LowerLimit GROUP BY cte.hhid;
```

And The result It produces:

```
| hhid | MaxDate    | avg_asset  | avg_income |
+------+------------+------------+------------+
|    2 | 2022-09-15 | 34464.0000 |  4650.6667 |
|    3 | 2022-07-06 |     0.0000 |     0.0000 |
|    4 | 2022-09-08 |     0.0000 |     0.0000 |
|    5 | 2022-10-09 | 21850.0000 |  3095.0000 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Your version should be minimum 8.0 , otherwise You can't use CTE in your queries. You can learn your version by running this simple code: SELECT version();

Comment: yes.my version is 5.7.It is not executing.could you help me on this.

Comment: This shows you how to do it, depending on your OS. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html

Comment: Thanks.Bt I access the db through a remote desktop connection where I cannot make changes.:(